# Group Data by Months

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter, pysimplegui

I have a dataframe in pandas

This code is part of a function in a GUI and I'm trying to create one line of string that would mention the amount of cases every month whereas the continent and location is selected from the user.

This is the dataset I am using: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv

Once user selects, a continent and location, for e.g. Asia, Singapore

My graph would show a line graph with the occurence of new deaths/total deaths/new cases against the dates. I'm trying to add one more line at plt.xlabel that summarizes the amount of cases every month

i.e. expected output: 'In Singapore for New cases, In January 2020, there are 50 cases, in February there 36 cases, in March there are 22 cases, in April there are 2 cases ...'

Here is my code:

```
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def graphUI(dfIn):
    # getting the continent and location to use as value for dropdown search
    df_continent = dfIn[1].drop_duplicates()
    df_location = dfIn[2].drop_duplicates()
    #for LinePlot Options
    linePlotList = ['New Case', 'Total Death', 'New Death']
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Display Graph')],
        [sg.Text('Continent:'),
         sg.Combo(df_continent.values[1:-1].tolist(), default_value="Continent", key="-continent-",change_submits=True)],
        [sg.Text('Location: '), sg.Combo(df_location.values[1:].tolist(), default_value="Location", key="-location-")],
        [sg.Text('Only For Line Plot: '), sg.Combo(linePlotList, default_value="New Case", key="-linePlot-")],
        [sg.Button('Bar plot', key='bar', tooltip='View Graph'),
         sg.Button('Line plot', key='line', tooltip='View Graph'),
         sg.Button('Cancel')]
    ]
    window = sg.Window('Search and Filter', layout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        #on combo continent changes value, it will run the code below
        if event == "-continent-":
            if values['-continent-'] != df_continent.values[0]:
                #run checkBoxUpdate function to update the list of country inside the selected continent
                formUpdate = checkBoxupdate(dfIn, values['-continent-'])
                #update the window by finding the element of location combo and update the latest country value
                window.FindElement('-location-').Update(values=formUpdate.values[1:].tolist())
        # Once user press Ok button, get all values and compare to df
        if event == "bar":
            searchedDf = dfIn[::]
            if values['-continent-'] != df_continent.values[0]:
                barchart(searchedDf,values)
        if event == "line":
            searchedDf = dfIn[::]
            if values['-location-'] != df_continent.values[1]:
                selectedLineChoice = values['-linePlot-']
                linePlot(searchedDf,values,selectedLineChoice)
        elif event == "Cancel" or event is None:
            window.close()
            return dfIn
```

Line plot function:

```
def linePlot(searchedDf, values,selectedLineChoice):
    # getting the continent and location to use as value for dropdown search
    searchedDf = searchedDf[searchedDf.isin([values['-location-']]).any(axis=1)]
    eachDate = list(searchedDf[3])
    if selectedLineChoice == 'New Case':
        selectedLineChoiceValues = list(map(int, searchedDf[5]))
    if selectedLineChoice == 'Total Death':
        selectedLineChoiceValues = list(map(int, searchedDf[6]))
    if selectedLineChoice == 'New Death':
        selectedLineChoiceValues = list(map(int, searchedDf[7]))

    #set frequency of the date on x axis to appear on lower freq
    frequency = 50
    plt.plot(eachDate , selectedLineChoiceValues)

    plt.xticks(eachDate[::frequency])
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=6)
    plt.suptitle('Total New Case of ' + values['-location-'])
    plt.xlabel('For' + values['-location-'] + 'in January 2020, there are' + x + 'cases, in February 2020, there are' + x + 'cases, in March 2020, there are' + x + 'cases, in April there are' + x + 'cases,'...)

    plt.ylabel(selectedLineChoice, fontsize=10)
    plt.show()

def checkBoxupdate(dfIn, input):
    #search the DF for the selected continents
    searchedDf = dfIn[dfIn.isin([input]).any(axis=1)]
    #drop duplicates country of the selected continenets and return
    df_location = searchedDf[2].drop_duplicates()
    return df_location
```

---

Example data from the link

```
iso_code,continent,location,date,total_cases,new_cases,new_cases_smoothed,total_deaths,new_deaths,new_deaths_smoothed,total_cases_per_million,new_cases_per_million,new_cases_smoothed_per_million,total_deaths_per_million,new_deaths_per_million,new_deaths_smoothed_per_million,total_tests,new_tests,total_tests_per_thousand,new_tests_per_thousand,new_tests_smoothed,new_tests_smoothed_per_thousand,tests_per_case,positive_rate,tests_units,stringency_index,population,population_density,median_age,aged_65_older,aged_70_older,gdp_per_capita,extreme_poverty,cardiovasc_death_rate,diabetes_prevalence,female_smokers,male_smokers,handwashing_facilities,hospital_beds_per_thousand,life_expectancy,human_development_index
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2019-12-31,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-01,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-02,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-03,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-04,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-05,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-06,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-07,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-08,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-09,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-10,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-01-11,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,,,0.0,38928341.0,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.498
```

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  Sometimes you might want to create fake data for the question - as long as it faithfully represents the actual data.. The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre].

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)